# Haskell : concat two IO Strings

Tags: string, function, haskell, functor

Today I have tried to concat two IO Strings and couldn't get it work.

So, the problem is: suppose we have `s1 :: IO String` and `s2 :: IO String`. How to implement function `(+++) :: IO String -> IO String -> IO String`, which works exactly as `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` but for IO String?

And more general question is how to implement more general function `(+++) :: IO a -> IO a -> IO a`? Or maybe even more general?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `liftM2` from `Control.Monad`:

```
liftM2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c


> :t liftM2 (++)
liftM2 (++) :: Monad m => m [a] -> m [a] -> m [a]
```

Alternatively, you could use `do` notation:

```
(+++) :: Monad m => m [a] -> m [a] -> m [a]
ms1 +++ ms2 = do
    s1 <- ms1
    s2 <- ms2
    return $ s1 ++ s2
```

---

Both of these are equivalent.  In fact, the definition for `liftM2` is implemented as

```
liftM2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
liftM2 f m1 m2 = do
    val1 <- m1
    val2 <- m2
    return $ f val1 val2
```

Very simple!  All it does is extract the values from two monadic actions and apply a function of 2 arguments to them.  This goes with the function `liftM` which performs this operation for a function of only one argument.  Alternatively, as pointed out by others, you can use `IO`'s `Applicative` instance in `Control.Applicative` and use the similar `liftA2` function.

You might notice that generic `Applicative`s have similar behavior to generic `Monad`s in certain contexts, and the reason for this is because they're mathematically very similar.  In fact, for every `Monad`, you can make an `Applicative` out of it.  Consequently, you can also make a `Functor` out of every `Applicative`.  There are a lot of people excited about the [Functor-Applicative-Monad proposal](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal) that's been around for a while, and is finally going to be implemented in an upcoming version of GHC.  They make a very natural hierarchy of `Functor > Applicative > Monad`.

Comment: By the way. I found one more solution. `(++) <$> s1 <*> s2`. It looks pretty good. But now I really have to meditate on everything I found :) Thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: @RottenBrain That answer uses the `Applicative` instance of `IO`.  The function `<*>` is actually equivalent to `Control.Monad.ap`, and `<$>` is just the infix version of `fmap`, which uses the `Functor` instance of `IO`.  Sometimes in Haskell the math lets you do something in several different ways =)

Comment: Hi again. I just finished "Learn You a Haskell" book and now I understand everything you told me. Anyway, thank you for your help. :)

Comment: @RottenBrain Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 5):

```
import Control.Applicative (liftA2)

(+++) :: Applicative f => f [a] -> f [a] -> f [a]
(+++) = liftA2 (++)
```

Now in GHCI

```
>> getLine +++ getLine
Hello <ENTER>
World!<ENTER>
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 5):

```
(++) <$> pure "stringOne" <*> pure "stringTwo"
```

Answer (score 4):

> implement function `(+++)` ... which works exactly as `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` but for `IO String`?

Don't do that, it's a bad idea. Concatenating strings is a purely functional operation, there's no reason to have it in the `IO` monad. Except at the place where you need the result – which would be somewhere in the middle of some other IO I suppose. Well, then just use `do`-notation to bind the read strings to variable names, and use ordinary `(++)` on them!

```
do
  print "Now start obtaining strings..."
  somePreliminaryActions
  someMoreIOStuff
  s1 <- getS1
  s2 <- getS2
  yetMoreIO
  useConcat'dStrings (s1 ++ s2)
  print "Done."
```

It's ok to make that more compact by writing `s12 <- liftA2 (++) getS1 getS2`. But I'd do that right in place, not define it seperately.

For longer operations you may of course want to define a seperate named action, but it should be a somehow meaningful one.

You shouldn't think of `IO String` objects as "IO-strings". They aren't, just as `[Int]` aren't "list-integers". An object of type `IO String` is an *action* which, when incurred, can supply a `String` object in the `IO` monad. It is not a string itself.